# Meteor server 'update' overwork

Tags: meteor

I have a server meteor app conected to MondoDB database. This database have a collectión with 14.000 docs updated from external application with 500 updates/second aprox.
This overload exaust my meteor server ( without clients ) reaching 100% cpu.

Any idea for optimize this process ?
Thanks.

Comment: This is pretty much the worst case scenario for a meteor app because every one of those writes will hit your oplog. I'd recommend using two databases with some aggregation layer in between.

Comment: Would redis be a good fit to act as cache for the documents?

Comment: @DavidWeldon have you found a way past oplog flooding? You mentioned this type of behaviour as a serious issue a few months ago (or maybe a year)

Comment: @Akshat My understanding is that it currently can't be avoided. I heard a rumor that with the upcoming mongo 3.0 there may be a way to limit what is sent. I suspect it will be a long while before meteor makes the upgrade though.